# How to type hint a subset of values from a known set in python

Tags: python, set, type-hinting

Consider the following set:

`s = set(["x", "y", "z"])`

How do I create a type hint for a variable that is any subset of the elements in s (short of explicitly creating a Union of every possible subset)?

Comment: What you are looking for are *refinement types*. Python has extremely limited support for them at this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get is annotating the variable as a set whose element type is a [literal type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal):

```
from typing import Literal

s2: set[Literal['x', 'y', 'z']] = # whatever
```

Type checkers will recognize that elements of such a set are one of these values, and they will prohibit adding elements that are not one of these values.

Type checkers will *not* recognize any particular subset relation between such a set and `s`, and they will not allow passing such a set to a function that takes `set[str]`, as such functions could add other strings to the set.

Comment: It's the "closest", but it's not really that close.